# Package dependency on two PPA

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, ppa

I have a package (`fcl`) in my PPA  in my launchpad PPA and it depends on another package (libccd) which is in another PPA `ppa:imnmfotmal/libccd`. `fcl` has both build and run dependency in `libccd`.

So i added `libccd` as a PPA dependency in launchpad and both are successfully build. but when i am trying to install `fcl` package after adding the fcl PPA, its throwing an error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fcl : Depends: libccd but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but its successfully getting installed after adding the `libccd` PPA also. I want `fcl` to install `libccd` automatically without adding its PPA. how can i achieve it ??

Output of `apt-cache policy fcl`

```
fcl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0-0ppa5
  Version table:
     1.0-0ppa5 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/imnmfotmal/fcl/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy fcl`

Comment: Ok, done. See my answer =)

Comment: You could simply copy  libccd from that other ppa to your ppa, then your ppa would not need a dep on the other ppa nor would any user of your ppa need to add the other ppa

Answer (score 0):

You are on Trusty and there is no package for `libccd` in Trusty. You need at least Utopic for this package without adding one more PPA. But you could do that:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:imnmfotmal/libccd
sudo update
sudo apt-get install fcl
```

The PPA is from the same maintainer of the `fcl` PPA.

---

And as you said

> i dont want the users to add both the libccd ppa and fcl ppa

Than you have to download and install the deb files from [here](https://launchpad.net/~imnmfotmal/+archive/ubuntu/libccd/+packages).

An other possibility is, create your own PPA and copy the packages into this PPA. Add this PPA to your system and use this.

Comment: there is a package  for libccd in trusty  see this : https://launchpad.net/~imnmfotmal/+archive/ubuntu/libccd/+packages  and it a ppa dependency of fcl also

Comment: i dont want the users to add both the libccd ppa and fcl ppa

Comment: ? You have already added a PPA. Where is the problem? Without that, you cant't use `fcl` in Trusty.

Comment: commented wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Copy libccd package from other PPA:libccd to yours (same PPA: fcl). Launchpad/LP supports that, easy: https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/Copying

  And it is up to you: copy only source package and rebuild it, or with binary too then they are served directly.
- Create/Add a recipe to build and upload libccd packages into same PPA: fcl. No use creating another PPA!